# How to fill a zeros matrix using for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

I have an array full of zeros created as A = np.zeros(m,m) and m = 6.
I want to fill this array with specific numbers that each equals sum of it's row and column number; such as A(x,y) = x+y.
How can i do this using for loop and while loop?

Comment: could you post the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Method that avoids a loop with rather significant performance improvement on a large ndarray:

```
A = np.zeros((6,6))
m = A.shape[0]
n = A.shape[1]

x = np.transpose(np.array([*range(1,m+1)]*n).reshape(n,m))
y = np.array([*range(1,n+1)]*m).reshape(m,n)
A = x+y

print(A)

[[ 2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = np.zeros((6,6))
for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
  for j in range(0, A.shape[1]):
    A[i][j] = i+j+2
```

If you want the rows and columns to be starting from 1, you can directly use this code, but if you want them to be starting from 0 you can surely remove the "+2" in line-4.

**Explanation:**
I am first traversing the row in a loop when, then traversing the columns in loop 2, and then I am accessing the cell value using A[i][j]. and assigning it to i+j+2 (or just i + j). This way the original array will fill your new values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
for y in range(len(A)):
  for x in range(len(A[Y]):
    A[y][x] = x + y
```